# How to print a table in php with a specific format for rows and columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table [image]

And my goals is to have a table looking like this

[image]

The table has 8 rows and 3 columns

I have already stored the questions but I'm having a hard time printing it in this format.

Wherein after printing 4 questions it will then go to another cell and print 4 questions again and then once there are already 3 columns it will then create a new row and do the same step again.( 8 rows and 3 columns)

The questions are ordered by sequence no. [In the table below the 1st 4 questions are 1,2,3,4 and then the cell on it's right are 6,7,8,9 and so on....]

I'm stuck with this for almost 8 hours already....

Here's my current code:

```
select = "SELECT q.QuestionID, q.QuestionText, q.m, q.l, q.GroupNo, q.SequenceNo FROM question2 q Order By q.SequenceNo";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$question_id = "";
$question_text = "";
$question_m = "";
$question_l = "";
$question_group = "";
//$table = "<table border='1' cellspacing='1'>";
$count_row = 0;
$array = array();
//$count_column = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $question_id = $row['QuestionID'];
    $question_text = $row['QuestionText'];
    $question_m = $row['m'];
    $question_l = $row['l'];
    $question_group = $row['GroupNo'];
    $question_sequence = $row['SequenceNo'];

    if($count_row > 2)
    {
        $array[] .= "</div>";   
    }

    $array[] .= "<div style='border=1px';'>";
    $array[] .= $question_text ."<br/>";
    $count_row++;
}

$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
```

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Comment: sound like array_chunk() can be useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question but you could try this.  I believe it will give you the output you want.

```
$row_count = 0;
echo "<table border=1>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($row_count%12 == 0) {
    echo "<tr>";
    }

    if($row_count%4 == 0) {
    echo "<td>";
    }

    echo $row['QuestionText']."<br>";

    if($row_count%4 == 3) {
    echo "</td>";
    }
    if($row_count%12 == 11) {
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    $row_count++;

}
echo "</table>";
```

It should give you an output that looks like this:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>0<br>1<br>2<br>3<br></td>
<td>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br></td>
<td>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br></td>
<td>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br></td>
<td>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br></td>
<td>28<br>29<br>30<br>31<br></td>
<td>32<br>33<br>34<br>35<br></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: Wow great solution sir. It worked perfectly. Do you have another way of doing this? I'm just curious sir. Thank you++ for the immediate reply. I owe you a lot. :D

Comment: anyway, it was a very good solution that you provided. wow, I wasn't able to come up with such solution for almost 8 hours and you did it with what? 10 mins. Thank you++ again sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
$querstions = array();
$query = "SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText, m, l, GroupNo, SequenceNo FROM question2 ORDER BY SequenceNo";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $querstions[$row['QuestionID']] = $row;
}

/* print table head */
echo "<table><thead>....

/* split up question in master_rows with 12 question each */
foreach(array_chunk($querstions, 12) as $master_row)
{
    echo ...

    foreach(range(0, 3) as $row_nr)
    {
        echo ... $master_row[$row_nr] ...;

        echo ... $master_row[$row_nr + 4] ...;

        echo ... $master_row[$row_nr + 8] ...;
    }

    echo ...
}
```